# Window popup is not closing in the Salesforce 1

Tags: salesforce1-app

I am opening the window pop up using window.open() and also close the window using window.close(). It is working fine in the Salesforce Classic but not working in the Salesforce 1. Please give any idea.

```
var win;
function authorizeGoogleDrive() 
        { 
            var code;
              _url        =   'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?'+  
              'client_id='+'{!clientId}'+  
                 '&response_type=code'+  
                 '&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'+  
                 '&redirect_uri='+'{!redirectUrl}'+
                 '&state=security_token'+
                 '&approval_prompt=force'+  
                 '&login_hint=jsmith@example.com&'+  
                 'access_type=offline'; 

                win         =   window.open(_url, "windowname1", 'width=800, height=600');

                var pollTimer   =   window.setInterval(function() 
                { 
                    try 
                    {
                        if (win.document.URL.indexOf('code') != -1) 
                        {
                            window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
                            var url =   win.document.URL;
                            code =   gup(url, 'code');
                            console.log('code = '+code);
                            windowClose();
                            getAccessToken(code);
                         }
                    } 
                    catch(e) 
                    {}
                }, 400);
        }

function windowClose() 
        {
            var pollTimer   =   window.setInterval(function() 
            { 
                try 
                {
                    if (win.document.URL.indexOf('code') != -1) 
                    {
                        win.close();
                    }
                } 
                catch(e) 
                {}
            }, 400);
        }
```